# VBA check if String element is empty

Tags: string, vba, excel

I am currently splitting strings containing 3 elements (a/b/c) from Worksheet 1 and pasting each part on Worksheet 2 in different columns. This is done by a Loop.

However, **if** the **string** has **only 2 elements**, so "c" from above is empty, I get a **Runtime Error 9: "Index out of Range"**.

The string can and will sometimes only have 1 or 2 elements instead of all 3. Is there any way I can avoid this error?

My research led me to try If Len(Trim()) = vbnullstring and Len() = 0 but nothing worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
For Each IDrow In wsInput.Range(IDcolLetter & "2:" & IDcolLetter & lastRow)

    'Fourthly, get the respective row-number for each skill
    IDrowNumber = Split(IDrow.Address, "$")(2)

    'Fifthly, split the strings in 3 parts
    Dim myElements() As String
    myElements = Split(wsInput.Range(IDcolLetter & IDrowNumber).value, "\")

    'Sixthly, for every skill of that supplier, copy the ID in A, CG in B, Category in C and Product in D
    NextRow = ws4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1

    If Len(myElements(2)) = 0 Then <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<ERROR HERE<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          wsInput.Range(IDcolLetter & "1").Copy Destination:=ws4.Range("A" & NextRow) 'ID
          ws4.Range("B" & NextRow) = myElements(0)                                 'Commodity Group
          ws4.Range("C" & NextRow) = myElements(1)                                 'Category
    Else
          wsInput.Range(IDcolLetter & "1").Copy Destination:=ws4.Range("A" & NextRow) 'ID
          ws4.Range("B" & NextRow) = myElements(0)                                 'Commodity Group
          ws4.Range("C" & NextRow) = myElements(1)                                 'Category
          ws4.Range("D" & NextRow) = myElements(2)                                 'Product
    End If


Next IDrow
```

Comment: try the code in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as much a code review as it is an answer.

- It's best to declare all your variables at the top of the procedure

IDrow is a range object.  Assuming IDrow.Address = `"A100"` then

- `Split(IDrow.Address, "$")(2) = 100`
- `IDrow.Row = 100`

These two values are also the same

- `wsInput.Range(IDcolLetter & IDrowNumber).value`
- `IDrow.value`

You are better off assigning the values of myElements by resizing the range to match the to number of element.  This is more readable; because it cleans up a lot of repetitive code.

`ws4.Range("B" & NextRow).Resize(1, UBound(myElements) + 1) = myElements`

Both of these lines do the same thing.   I am trying to promote the later pattern because I feel is cleaner and easier to read.

- `For Each IDrow In wsInput.Range(IDcolLetter & "2:" & IDcolLetter & lastRow)`
- `For Each IDrow In wsInput.Columns(IDcolLetter).Rows("2:" & lastRow)`

---

```
Dim myElements() As String

With wsInput

    For Each IDrow In wsInput.Columns(IDcolLetter).Rows("2:" & lastRow)
        'Fifthly, split the strings in 3 parts
        myElements = Split(IDrow.Value, "\")

        'Sixthly, for every skill of that supplier, copy the ID in A, CG in B, Category in C and Product in D
        NextRow = ws4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        .Range(IDcolLetter & "1").Copy Destination:=ws4.Range("A" & NextRow)
        ws4.Range("B" & NextRow).Resize(1, UBound(myElements) + 1) = myElements

    Next IDrow

End With
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time for this extensive Elaboration. I am always happy to learn and I will adjust my future code this way. One question though: Would this code post all 3 string-elements or would I need `ws4.Range("B" & NextRow).Resize(1, UBound(myElements)) = myElements(0)` , `ws4.Range("C" & NextRow).Resize(1, UBound(myElements)) = myElements(1)` and `ws4.Range("D" & NextRow).Resize(1, UBound(myElements)) = myElements(2)` ?

Comment: Thomas, I just adapted your Approach and it does not include the 3rd part of the string - "Products". Do you have any idea why? See here: http://imgur.com/a/EWnRp

Comment: Sorry about that.  Because `myElements` is a zero base array,I should have added 1 to the `Ubound` of `myElements`: `ws4.Range("B" & NextRow).Resize(1, UBound(myElements) + 1)`

Comment: Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Thomas, my apologies for bothering you again. Is it possible to set a definitie range to cells B2, C3 and D4, and save the elements there, thereby using the resize-function? I am having Trouble working with strings that only have 1 or 2 elements..

Comment: My apologies. My string usually has 3 elements - x\y\z. This string is used to populate a TreeView at a later point. To make this work, I Need to save x in cell B2, y in cell C3 and z in cell D4. In addition, the string can have only 1 or 2 elements (a or a\b). Now, I am having the same problem as described above - that if the string only has 1 or 2 instead of 3 elements, I get an error. My question is whether one can use Resize (or sth. else) to populate B2, C3 and D4 depending on the string size.

Comment: I'm confused about `"B2, C3 and D4"`. Do you mean to use 3 different columns and 3 different rows? Or do you mean `x\y\z` should populate `B2,C2,D2`  but `y\z` should only populate `C2,D2`?

Comment: Assuming a string consisting of X\Y\Z as possible elements: if we only have X, it should populate B2, if we have X\Y, X should go into B2 and Y into C3, if we have X\Y\Z, X should go into B2, Y into C3 and Z into D4

Comment: This is the only reason. If you have a look at the file I sent you, you can have a look at the "PopulateTreeViewFromString"-Module and there on the bottom of the first Sub, after the last `Else`. Or look here: http://imgur.com/a/DrZ9z I found it on the Internet and did not know any better way to populate the second TreeView with the skills on the "Search and Edit" Tab of UserForm1. The whole Problem only arose because having only one skill-entry for an ID led to an error, as decribed in the code-comment on the first Image.

Comment: What was the email address?

Comment: I will email you in a second

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `UBound(myElements)` to get the number of elements in **myElements** array after the `Split`.

Add the following code to your existing code:

```
'Fifthly, split the strings in 3 parts
Dim myElements() As String
myElements = Split(wsInput.Range(IDcolLetter & IDrowNumber).Value, "\")

Dim arrCount    As Long
' count the upper bound limit of myElements array
arrCount = UBound(myElements)

' if there is an Element 3 (from Split function)
If arrCount >= 2 Then
    ' add the rest of your code here...

End If
```

Comment: @Intermind, do you really prefer to use an `If-Then` block (plus additional variables) instead of a single line (see my answer)? Keep this answer accepted, but _please_ get accustomed to "lean" code...

Comment: @user3598756 honestly I do not prefer anything because I started with VBA about 6 weeks ago and thus do not know the differences between each method. So far I am just happy that it works.Moreover, I did not know how to implement your solution into my code.

Comment: you just substitute your code from `If Len(myElements(2)) = 0 Then...` to `End If` with that simple line...

Comment: @InternInNeed so after all the pressure you were put on you gave up and removed my "Answer" ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I did not know that your answer would be deleted after I changed the green tick... I did not delete it manually or on purpose.

Comment: @InternInNeed it's not deleted, just removed my answer "as Answer" , but if Thomas's answer is more suitable for you then use it

Comment: It was, since I run into problems when with the greater sign since the Array can also have 1 element only and having >=2 and >=1 or so in the code was contradicting each other. I bet your answer could have been adjusted, but I simply do not know how yet. My apologies that you lost the points.

Comment: @InternInNeed it's ok, let me know if you need help fixing it

Comment: @ShaiRado I was wondering if you can help me with a short Problem that is similar. I would like to save each part (of the 3) of the string into the cells B2, C3 and D4, respectively. How would that be possible using `ws4.Range("B" & NextRow).Resize(1, UBound(myElements) + 1) = myElements` ? If the user in my UserForm saves a string with only 1 or 2 parts, I am encountering an Error - and it Needs to be possible to save such a string.

Comment: @InternInNeed Since this is not part of my solution, I am not sure how to follow the line of logics, ask Thomas I guess

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
ws4.Range("B" & NextRow).Resize(, UBound(myElements)).Value = myElements
```